# Widget's IntentService needs access to other class' variable - how to create this test condition?

Tags: android, classloader, widget

I have defined a widget with a button waiting for the user to press "OK".
Once the button is pressed it fires the IntentService `ExecuteButton`.

This  `ExecuteButton`accesses the variable `status` of DataClass.

What happens if the `DataClass` has been unloaded by the Android system while the widget is waiting for the user to press OK ? This could potentially be couple of hours until the user presses OK - for sure the DataClass should be unloaded by then.

To test this I would need to unload the `DataClass` and see if it just gets reloaded correctly.

Is there a way to enforce unloading of classes in Android (except of rebooting the device?)

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What happens if the DataClass has been unloaded by the Android system while the widget is waiting for the user to press OK ? This could potentially be couple of hours until the user presses OK - for sure the DataClass should be unloaded by then.

Android does not unload classes. It terminates your process. So, either everything is there, or nothing is there.

Comment: ...so the app process is terminated during the 60 secs waiting time until the widget is updated. Then the process starts to update the widget, loading the classes ( if they are not in memory). This is exactly the situation I like to test. The process starts, does NOT find the classes in memory, LOADS what is required and fires the corresponding onCreates. The onCreates are NOT fired if the classes ARE still in memory, even though the app process has terminated and restarts. The process will REUSE the existing classes in memory. - this is my understanding so far - or is it wrong?

Comment: @user387184: You can terminate your process manually via the Devices view, typically accessed via the DDMS perspective. Highlight your process in the list and click the red STOP icon in the toolbar.

Comment: @user387184: "this is my understanding so far - or is it wrong?" -- sounds reasonable, though many times your process will actually survive the intervening minute.

Comment: stopping the process does not enforce unloading the classes, so I cannot really test what happens if some classes need to get loaded once the widget gets updated.... In my case I need to know what is shown on the widget and I keep this in a DB shadowed by a DataClass. If the user presses the "OK" button and the DataClass is not there anymore I have to access the DB. while accessing the DB requires a context that I create in this case. This is why I need to test the case when my DataClass is not accessible anymore from the widget update method - I hope I could explain ...

Comment: @user387184: "stopping the process does not enforce unloading the classes" -- then I have no idea what you think "unloading the classes" means.

Comment: now I understand! the widget itself does not have a process while its waiting to be updated. Somehow Android fires the onUpdate method to the AppWidgetProvider, this starts the process again. So stop actually works on the app, I just did not see it since the "Active App" widget did not show it, but DDMS was OK - you were right! By the way is there a way to give the widget itself some memory like an object variable that stays with the widget and can be accessed - never gets lost - only if one trashes the widget?

Comment: @user387184: "the widget itself does not have a process while its waiting to be updated" -- correct. Your `AppWidgetProvider` lives long enough to process an `onUpdate()` (or whatever) request, then is discarded. What lives on -- your actual app widget UI -- is in the home screen's process. "By the way is there a way to give the widget itself some memory like an object variable that stays with the widget and can be accessed - never gets lost - only if one trashes the widget?" -- only in the form of a persistent store, like a file or database.

Comment: "only in the form of a persistent store, like a file or database" => this is how I have done it. - Again, thank you very much for your help on this one! ps. I wonder where do you find all the time programming & learning so much in depth while answering all these questions :-)